# Deleting white background from scans in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections, white-space

I'm trying to create custom brushes in illustrator with scanned brushstrokes.  I use image trace, then expand...how do you then select and delete the white background?

Comment: Read: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27583/transparency-is-lost-in-illustrator-cs6-when-i-use-image-trace-help/27593#27593 basically you want to turn the option ignore white on. OTOH you can just select white and delete too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above by @joojaa, you have to tick the "Ignore white" in the advanced settings in trace window. If this option is disabled/grayed out then make sure you pick the first method type (Abutting). Since you have already traced the brush, you can use the magic wand tool to select all white shapes and then you can remove them

Comment: A good way to go - worked right away.  Thank you!